# How to set the library build order in gradle?

Tags: java, android, build, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a custom android.jar which overrides the default android classes and needs to be build before the default android.jar .In eclipse I can set the order in the tab of 'Order and Export'。But now I'm using gradle in android studio,what should i do?

Any ideas? Any clarification needed?
Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: read section 51.7   http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html

Comment: can you give me more details,I'm a new newcomer to gradle.

Comment: Post your `build.gradle`.

Answer (score 1):

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
}
```

Like this you can build jar files

Answer (score -2):

If you right click on your project and click "Open Module Settings" you should see a tab that says "Dependencies". After you click on the tab you should see a green plus button, clicking on it will give you 3 options. Select "Module Dependency" and from there you can add your jar. It should automatically update the gradle for you.